# What is the fastest method to find which of $\frac {3\sqrt {3}-4}{7-2\sqrt {3}} $ and $\frac {3\sqrt {3}-8}{1-2\sqrt {3}} $ is bigger manually?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, radicals, fractions, mental-arithmetic

What is the fastest method to find which number is bigger manually?

$\frac {3\sqrt {3}-4}{7-2\sqrt {3}} $ or $\frac {3\sqrt {3}-8}{1-2\sqrt {3}} $

Comment: put rt(3) =1(appox) and see the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the rule $a\sqrt b=\sqrt{a^2b}$ for $a,b>0$ one checks the signs of numerator and denominator to be both positive for the first fraction and both negative for the second fraction. This is therefore a comparison of two positive numbers (so no verdict yet), and by flipping the signs of numerator and denominator on the right we can ensure that all individual factors are positive: compare $\frac{3\sqrt3-4}{7-2\sqrt3}$ and $\frac{8-3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3-1}$. Now multiply by the (positive!) product of the denominators to compare $(3\sqrt3-4)(2\sqrt3-1)$ and $(8-3\sqrt3)(7-2\sqrt3)$ which amounts to comparing $22-11\sqrt3$ and $74-37\sqrt3$ or finally $26\sqrt3$ and $52$. Since by happy coincidence $26\times2=52$ and $\sqrt3<2$ the number on the left is smaller.

I'm not sure whether many people could do this easily by mental arithmetic (I certainly did not). Each of the terms in the final comparison are obtained by adding $4$ products from the terms in the original expression. One product, namely $(2\sqrt3)(3\sqrt3)$, contributes twice with opposite signs and could therefore have been cancelled beforehand (leaving $7\times8-4\times1=52$ for that term), but that's all I can see for simplifications. Personally my main problem with mental computation is that I very often get the sign of one term wrong in my head, but maybe with a lot of training one can limit this kind of errors.

Answer (score 8):

I would multiply by the conjugate of denominator $$a=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}-4}{7-2 \sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{37} \left(13 \sqrt{3}-10\right)$$ $$b=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}-8}{1-2 \sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{11} \left(13 \sqrt{3}-10\right)$$ this makes $a<b$.

Comment: Nice approach (+1)

Comment: That certainly is a happy coincidence. An indication that something like this _might_ happen can be found in the "field norms" (term to be interpreted in the field $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 3]$, just like your "conjugate", so $a^2-3b^2$ for $a\pm b\sqrt3$) of denominators and numerators are $27-16=11$, $49-12=37$, $27-64=- 37$ and $1-12=-11$. So "numerator times conjugate denominator" gives the same norm on both sides, and they just might actually be equal.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen. I totally agree with you about the happy coincidence. Thanks for your interesting comment !

Comment: Unlike the officially approved answer, I actually can do this in my head!

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{3\sqrt3-8}{1-2\sqrt3}=\dfrac{8-3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3-1}$$

Now $$\dfrac{3\sqrt3-4}{7-2\sqrt3}-\dfrac{8-3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3-1}=\dfrac{(3\sqrt3-4)(2\sqrt3-1)-(7-2\sqrt3)(8-3\sqrt3)}{(7-2\sqrt3)(2\sqrt3-1)}$$

$$=\dfrac{26\sqrt3-52}{(7-2\sqrt3)(2\sqrt3-1)}$$

Now  the denominator $>0,$ and $26\sqrt3-52=26(\sqrt3-2)<0$

Answer (score 2):

Using the approximation $\sqrt3\approx1.7$, one can do a bit of mental arithmetic and see that

$${3\sqrt3-4\over7-2\sqrt3}\approx{1.1\over3.6}\lt1\qquad\text{while}\qquad{3\sqrt3-8\over1-2\sqrt3}\approx{-2.9\over-2.4}={2.9\over2.4}\gt1$$

This only works, of course, because the two numbers are not at all close.  It's also not a rigorous proof, although it could be turned into one with a little more care.  For example, since $\sqrt3\lt2$, we have

$${3\sqrt3-4\over7-2\sqrt3}\lt{6-4\over7-4}={2\over3}\qquad\text{while}\qquad{3\sqrt3-8\over1-2\sqrt3}={8-3\sqrt3\over2\sqrt3-1}\gt{8-6\over4-1}={2\over3}$$

(Note the element of luck here, in that the two crude bounds happen to agree.)

Comment: I was coming here to add a similar answer. Even if one doesn't recall the approximation for $\sqrt3$ it can be calculated with a few digits of precision quite quickly with a digit by digit square root algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**

$$\frac {3\sqrt {3}-4}{7-2\sqrt {3}}<\frac {3\sqrt {3}-8}{1-2\sqrt {3}}$$

**Proof:**

Let $u=\sqrt 3-1$. Notice $1>u>\frac12$.

If

$$\frac{3u-1}{5-2u}<\frac{3u-5}{-2u-1}$$
$$\Leftarrow-6u^2-u+1>-6u^2+25u-25$$
$$\Leftarrow26>26u$$
$$\Leftarrow1>u=\sqrt3-1$$

which is true.

Comment: What was the motivation to give that particular number the name$~u$? Also for the presentation, you should not start by assuming the conclusion and deriving a true statement from it (you are in fact reasoning backwards $\Leftarrow$, which is OK for the steps you make, but should be mentioned correctly in the text).

Comment: I did that substitution intentionally. It is not hard to notice that all the denominators and numerators are in form of $a\sqrt3 + b$. Just with an attempt to make the expression simpler. I will change the presentation, though.